# Open firefox and start typing to the address bar immediately

Tags: firefox-for-android, search

Is it possible to set up firefox such that whenever it opens, it is "focused" to the address bar? So that whenever I open firefox, the keyboard opens as well and I can immediately start writing to the address bar?

Comment: Android version and Android device? Is it rooted?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google search you can start typing and web address and it should open in your default browser (Firefox if you have it set like default)

You can also add the Firefox search widget to your home screen as well if you want to get Firefox search suggestions.